# Chrome opens website and Immediately Closes when Using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, bots

Chrome Version : 110.0.5481.104
Chrome Driver Version: 110.0.5481.77
*From What I have heard last digits of the version do not matter.*

Its just a Simple Piece of Code:-

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
os.environ['PATH'] =r"C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx/Selenium/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe"
driver=webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://phptravels.com/demo/")
```

Chrome Opens up shows the Website and then Immediately Closes. If the Version is the issue, please inform from which version I should be Downloading as there is no version which ends with 104.

Also something that Might be Worth mentioning...VS Code is Showing me a weird error in the terminal:

```
USB: usb_device_handle_win.cc:1046 Failed to read descriptor from node connection: A device attached to the system is not functioning. (0x1F)
```

Thanks Your Help will be appreciated.

Comment: it should close. driver got the website, since there are no other instructions, it just closes.

Comment: Even when I add other instructions it still just closes.....

Comment: Try adding this code `time.sleep(10)` after `driver.get` line. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your program is ended at line 5, and so did selenium.

Try adding an `input()` at the end so the program will wait for user input before exiting.

Better:

```
# It doesn't wait for user input but
# will close on Ctrl+C
while True:
    try:
        time.sleep(1);
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break;
```